# How to do error handling when using Future.flow - CPS Continuation Passing Style

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to implement error handling in below function. My problem is that I need to unwrap Future[Either[Exception,MyValue]] and test for "Right" every time I what to use the MyValue as a param.

The strategy is to let the Future.flow fail if any of the f1 to f4 fails.

One solution is to pass the Either[Exception,MyValue] as a param to the funcReturnFutureEitherX() like funcReturnFutureEither3(f2()) but this just propagate the error handling downwards instead of handling it in the main program MyFlowFunc().

How do I implement error handling in the below function and keep it running none blocking ?

```
def MyFlowFunc():Future[(MyValue,MyValue,MyValue,MyValue)] =
    val v = Future.flow {
        // fail flow if below functions fails with a Either.Left() 
        val f1 = funcReturnFutureEither1()   
        val f2 = funcReturnFutureEither2(f1())
        val f3 = funcReturnFutureEither3(f2())
        val f4 = funcReturnFutureEither4(f1())
        val res = (f1(),f2(),f3(),f4())
    }
}
def funcReturnEitherX(val:MyValue):Future[Either[Exception,MyValue]]
```

Comment: Ok, Found the answer myself. Don't do any error handling with Either or Option just use
fallbackTo(Future(None)). which will translate into v.fallbackTo(Future(None)) in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `scalaz`, the following will probably make sense. If not, it can be interesting to read about it:

`Either[L,R]` is isomorphic to `Validation[E,A]`, however the latter is usually used as an `Applicative Functor`. Since `Future` is also an applicative functor, their composed type of `Future[Validation[E, A]]` is also an Applicative.

Then you could just use the `|@|` operator to combine the arguments and pass them into a contextless function. In practice you might need to write an `Applicative` typeclass for `Future`.

**Update**: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3005729) for example code.

Comment: By the way, this sounds so fun that I might try to implement it in practice and come back with an example.